# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Trying to add to list

Tags: vb.net

I've created A list of object "emails" which contains the "email" object which has 3 parameters (String Address, String Subject, String Body)

I then want to add to the list by creating more instances of "email". However, I've tried so many different ways and it's having none of it.

```
Public Class Test

   Public emails As List(Of Email)

   Private Sub Test_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      emails(0).setAddress("Hello")
      emails(0).setSubject("World2")
      emails(0).setBody("Why don't you work?")
      emails.Add(New Email("Hello2", "World2", "Why don't you work?2"))

   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Label1.Text = emails(0).getAddress
       Label2.Text = emails(0).getSubject
       Label3.Text = emails(0).getBody

       Label4.Text = emails(1).getAddress
       Label5.Text = emails(1).getSubject
       Label6.Text = emails(1).getBody
   End Sub
End Class
```

If I click button1 I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have not created an instance of the list, you have only declared it.

```
 Public emails As New List(Of Email) 
 '                ^^^
```